# Negative pattern in Pathlib.rglob() function

Tags: python-3.6, pathlib

I need to find all python file in folder excluding __init__.py
My first attempt was

```py
import re
search_path.rglob(re.compile("(?!__init__).*.py"))
```

Such code fails, so i end up with:

```py
filter(
  lambda path: '__init__.py' != path.name and path.name.endswith('.py') and path.is_file(), search_path.rglob("*.py")
)
```

Looks like rglob does not support python regexps.

- Why?
- Does rglob supports negative patterns?
- Can this code be more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

I need something very much like this too. I came up with this:

```
import pathlib

search_path = pathlib.Path.cwd() / "test_folder"
for file in filter(lambda item: item.name != "__init__.py", search_path.rglob("./*.py")):
    print(f"{file}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fnmatch.html).

```
import pathlib
import fnmatch

search_path = pathlib.Path.cwd() / "test_folder"
for file in search_path.rglob("./*.py"):
    if not fnmatch.fnmatch(file.name, "__init__.py"):
        print(f"{file}")
```